# How do I do this sql query in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

How do I do this sql query in Zend Framework, I need to some how do this in the PDO context I think? I tried ->query but not sure if I am getting this right. The three variables are user_id and to and from date.

```
SELECT 
 ss.subcategory_id,
 ss.subcategory_name,
 ss.subcategory_issaving,
 IFNULL(SUM(m.mv_monthly_total),0) AS expendsum
FROM
 (SELECT
    s.subcategory_id,
    s.subcategory_name,
    s.subcategory_issaving
FROM
    subcategory s
  WHERE 
    s.subcategory_isexpend = 'Y'
  AND 
    s.subcategory_issaving = 'Y') ss
LEFT JOIN 
  mv_monthly m
ON ss.subcategory_id = m.mv_monthly_subcategory_id
AND m.mv_monthly_user_id = 2
AND m.mv_monthly_month >= '2010-01-01'
AND m.mv_monthly_month <= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY  
 ss.subcategory_id,
 ss.subcategory_name,
 ss.subcategory_issaving
ORDER BY
 ss.subcategory_issaving DESC,
 expendsum;
```

I have tried the following with no luck

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $dbExpr1 = new Zend_Db_Expr("s.subcategory_id, s.subcategory_name, s.subcategory_issaving");
    $dbExpr2 = new Zend_Db_Expr("ss.subcategory_id, ss.subcategory_name, ss.subcategory_issaving, IFNULL(SUM(m.mv_monthly_total),0) AS expendsum");   
    $select = $db->select()
        ->from(
            array(
                'ss' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    '('. $db->select()
                        ->from(array("s" => "subcategory"), $dbExpr1)
                        ->where("s.subcategory_isexpend = 'Y'")
                        ->where("s.subcategory_issaving = 'Y'") .')'
                )
            ),
            $dbExpr2
        )
        ->joinLeft(array("m" => "mv_monthly"), "ss.subcategory_id = m.mv_monthly_subcategory_id")
        ->where("m.mv_monthly_user_id = ?", $user_id)       
        ->where("m.mv_monthly_month >= ?", $fromMonth)
        ->where("m.mv_monthly_month <= ?", $toMonth)
        ->group(array("ss.subcategory_id","ss.subcategory_name","ss.subcategory_issaving"))
        ->order(array("ss.subcategory_issaving DESC", "expendsum"));
    $row = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: I think you have to seriously start considering the use of views.

Comment: unfortunatly views are not an option for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a complex query, you can just execute it directly rather than using the object oriented approach as it gets fairly complicated with a query like that.

Try something like this, replacing my query with yours, and binding your variables into the query:

```
    $db   = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($db, 'SELECT a, b, c FROM a WHERE username = ? AND date = ?');

    try {
        $res  = $stmt->execute(array($user_id, $fromMonth));

        if ($res) {
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
    } catch (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception $dbex) {
        // log Query failed with exception $dbex->getMessage();
    }
```

If you prefer to use the object oriented approach, or need to because some parts of the query will be conditional, I usually build by subqueries up first as their own select, and you can simply embed those in to the main query with the select object for the subquery.

Here is what I mean by that:

```
    $subselect = $this->getDbTable()
                      ->select()
                      ->from('mytable', array('time' => 'max(time)', 'id'))
                      ->where('id IN (?)', $serialNumbers)
                      ->group('id');

    $select    = $this->getDbTable()
                      ->select()
                      ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                      ->from('mytable')
                      ->join('other', 'mytable.id = other.id', array('label'))
                      ->join(array('dt' => $subselect),
                             '(mytable.time, mytable.id) = (dt.time, dt.id)', '');
```